# angular ng-repeat animation adds two elements to the DOM

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to achieve a very simple ng-repeat animation.

- animate items added
- animate items removed

I would like to use keyframe animations, so I have defined two classes in my CSS.

```
.add-rem-anim.ng-leave {
  animation: slideOutFrames ease 1000s;
}

.add-rem-anim.ng-enter {
  animation: slideInFrames ease 1000s;
}
```

When I add/remove an element to the collection, somehow I end up having the new item twice in the DOM. Once with ng-leave (why?) and once with ng-enter.

Here is the ng-repeat code I use:

```
<div class="form-group row datalist-item add-rem-anim" ng-repeat="article in articles.articles | filter:articles.search track by $index">
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: this much information or code wont let any one understand whats wrong in the code. create a plunk and provide more data , like add /remove code and how articles array is been created

Comment: AngularJS version?

Comment: Show the animation CSS.

Comment: unfortunately on the plunk I created it works. So I tried a very simple version in my code base and it works too. The difference is that in the app I use Meteor with Angular and I add a new document to a collection. I will try to figure out more, sorry does not seem to be related to Angular directly.

Comment: It's the way Meteor tries to guess what a server side call does (it adds the newly created item to the collection before it is actually persisted). This is pretty cool, as in most cases the effect on the collection can be guessed quite well. When the server then persists the item and notifies the client about the change I guess the simulated item is replaced (i.e. removed!). Therefore it seems like having the item twice in my collection during the animation. I can prevent this by using Meteor.isServer. Better ideas are very welcome (maybe custom track by function?).